# How To Store and Retrieve Secrets From Hashicorp Vault using Docker-Compose?

Tags: docker, encryption, docker-compose, hashicorp-vault, docker-secrets

I have setup an instance of Hashicorp Vault. I have successfully written and read secrets to and from it. Getting Vault up and running and is the easy part. Now, **how do I use Vault as a store to replace the .env file in docker-compose.yml?** How do I read secrets from Vault in all of my docker-compose files?

Even more difficult: how do I dynamically generate keys to access access the secrets in Vault, then use those keys in my docker-compose.yml files, without editing those files each time I restart a stack? How is that process automated? In short, just exactly how can I leverage Hashicorp Vault to secure the secrets that are otherwise exposed in the .env files?

I have read all of their literature and blog posts, and haven't been able to find anything that outlines that process. I am stuck and any tips will be greatly appreciated.

*Note: This is not a question about running a Hashicorp Vault container with docker-compose, I have successfully done that already.*

*Also Note: I cannot modify the containers themselves; I can only modify the docker-compose.yml file*

Answer (score 1):

You would need to query the vault API to populate either your `.env` file or in the entrypoint of your container. My preference would be the container entrypoint at worst, and ideally directly in your application. The reason is because vault secrets could be short lived, and any container running for longer than that period would need to refresh it's secrets.

If you go with the worst case of doing this in the entrypoint, there are a few tools that come to mind. [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd) from Kelsey Hightower, and [gomplate](https://github.com/hairyhenderson/gomplate).

`confd` can run as a daemon and restart your app inside the container when the configuration changes. My only concern is that it is an older and less maintained project.

`gomplate` would be run by your entrypoint to expand a template file with the needed values. That file could just be an `env.sh` that you then source into your environment if you needed env vars. Or you can run it within your command line as a subshell, e.g.

```
your-app --arg "$(gomplate ...sometemplate...)"
```

If you only use these tools to set the value once and then start your app, make sure to configure a healthcheck and/or graceful exit your app when the credentials expire. Then run your container with orchestration (Kubernetes/Swarm Mode) or set a restart policy so that it restarts after any credentials expire to get the new credentials.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. I probably should have mentioned that I am trying to apply this to my existing stacks. Meaning I cannot edit the entrypoint, or modify the containers in any way; I can only edit the docker-compose file. I simply wish to replace the .env file as a means for secrets storage.

Comment: You can run `gomplate` on the host to build the `.env`, but that assumes your secrets never change between deploys. And it also assumes you don't mind your secrets being stored in clear text on the filesystem and visible in the container inspect. Goes against all the value of vault.

Comment: So then confd and gomplate are 110% out of the question: I mean why add so many levels of complexity and abstraction to achieve exactly the same result? Is there no way to provide encryption for docker-compose.yml environment variables? I assumed it would be a straightforward feature in Vault, which is the only reason I had even considered using Vault in the first place.

Comment: That is why I suggest doing it either in the entrypoint at worst, or within the application itself at best.

Comment: See my answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76126365/5098156). You can load KVs from shell in `docker-compose.yml` after fetching KVs from Vault using CLI.

Comment: @BMitch I wonder what you think about the solution by Darkato.

Comment: @its.me.adam it doesn't handle expiring secrets gracefully. Otherwise it's largely the same as the `.env` suggestion at the very beginning.