# Storing default environment variables in Vault instead of env files in docker-compose for standard services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hashicorp-vault

I have a `docker-compose` stack which uses standard software containers like:

- **InfluxDB**
- **MariaDB**
- **Node-Red**

running on a Industrial Single Board Computer (which may not be connected to the internet)

for initial setup (bringing the stack up), I pass some standard credentials like admin credentials via their environment variable files e.g. `influxdb.env`, `mariadb.env` etc.

A typical example of a `docker-compose.yml` here is:

```yaml
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.0
    env_file:
      - influxdb.env
  nodered:
    image: nodered/node-red:2.2.2
    env_file:
      - node-red.env
```

An example of `influxdb.env` could be:

```
INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin
INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password!#$2
# other env vars that might be crucial for initial stack boot up
```

These files are on the disk and can still be vulnerable. I wish to understand if Hashicorp Vault can provide a plausible solution where such credentials (secrets) can be stored as key-value pairs and be made available to the docker-compose services upon runtime.

I understand one bottleneck that since I am using *standard containers* (ready-to-use) and they may not have vault integration. However, can I still use vault to store the env vars and let the services access them on runtime? Or do I have to write *side-cars* for these containers and then let them accept these env var values?

Comment: Do you control the execution of `docker-compose`? And when it does run, does it have access to Vault (internally, without going to the internet on HCP for example)?

Comment: I do have control of execution, I am planning to introduce vault as a container in the `docker-compose` file so it would mean that vault with some baked information will be available on-board @ixe013

Comment: if you're using git, you can try age/sops git filters: https://devops.datenkollektiv.de/using-sops-with-age-and-git-like-a-pro.html

Comment: Did one of the answers work for you? Do you mind accepting the best one?

Answer (score 2):

A working solution similar to [ixe013's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71739207/5098156) without saving files:

1. Fetch key-value pairs from vault in yaml format
2. Set environment variables using the key-value pairs
3. Populate values inside `docker-compose.yml` from Shell's environment variables. see [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-from-the-shell)

---

**Details:**

- KVs stored in Vault shown below:

[image: KVs in Vault]

- Define an `export_secrets()` function

```bash
export_secrets() {
  echo "Input data:"
  echo "$1"
  
  while read -r line; do
    key=$(echo $line | cut -d: -f1 | xargs)
    value=$(echo $line | cut -d: -f2 | xargs)

    echo "Parsed key-value pair: $key=$value"
    
    export $key="$value"
    
    echo "Exported environment variable: $(printenv "$key")"
  done
}
```

- Set environment values from Vault

```bash
vault kv get -format=yaml -field=data -mount=secret appsecrets_demo | export_secrets
```

- Verify them by `echo $DATABASE_PASSWORD`
- In `docker-compose.yml`, substitute from the shell

```yaml
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.0
    environment:
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: '${DATABASE_PASSWORD}'
```

- I verified this solution with a second vault server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a few constraints to work with here:

- Not storing secrets permanently in storage
- `docker-compose` command line
- Vault's output format

Docker composer can read it's environment variables from a file. I suggest that you create that file and provide it to `docker-compose` with the `--env-file` parameter.

I can think of two approach to write that file:

1. Write the output of multiple `vault kv get` to a file, in `NAME=VALUE` format
2. Use vault agent's template engine

The first option is quite straighforward. Call a function that outputs the secrets and send it to a file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function write_vault_secret_to_env_file() {
    local ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME=$1
    local SECRET_PATH=$2
    local SECRET_NAME=$3

    echo "$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME=$(vault kv get --field $SECRET_NAME $SECRET_PATH)"
}

echo "$(write_vault_secret_to_env_file FIRST_ENVIROMENT_VAR secret/my-path/things first-secret)" >> my-env-file.sh 
echo "$(write_vault_secret_to_env_file SECOND_ENVIROMENT_VAR secret/my-path/stuff second-secret)" >> my-env-file.sh
```

[Vault agent 's template engine](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/agent/template) is much more powerfull, but is more complex to set up.

Another suggestion would be to use Vault's dynamic secrets for databases ([InfluxDB is supported](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/influxdb)). But you need to provide Vault with DBA privileges in your database. If you create the database from scratch everytime, you could make the DBA password `dba-root`, give Vault that password and [instruct it to rotate it for you](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/databases#rotate-root-credentials).

Comment: but doesn't this defeat the purpose of using vault? I want to store credentials in vault so as to avoid saving them in environment files in the first place. Irrespective of the secret is encrypted or not.

Comment: It is not ideal, but at least the file is generated just in time and (maybe) you can make it ephemeral. The alternative would be to edit the runtime or image of InfluxDB to have it read its credentials from Vault. And even if was able to do that, you would still have to provide InfluxDB with a way to authenticate to Vault! There is also the possibility to use dynamic database password, see my edited response.